# Last 12 month avg in tableau label ( not using any table detail only with label)

Tags: tableau-api

Need your help in creating last 12 month avg in tableau put it in a single label

here I tried using window_avg i am able to get the 12 months avg but if i use it label / showing single value for the last month .. it is not working

WINDOW_AVG(SUM([Balance Total]),-11,0)

I am not able to add the sample file so added image .. the expected output is 392306.6 ... or any logic with sample data would be more helpful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keep your working window avg calc. Create an LAST calculated field.

```
LAST()
```

Place it in the filter shelf and set values to zero.

[image]

This will hide all other dates in the view but keep the correct window calculation. LAST does not need to be in the view. I only showed it for demo purposes on the screenshot above.

[image]